# Get radio button value in controller of asp.net mvc by jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have list of radio button in my views like this  :

```
<input type="radio" name="questionOpt[1]" value="Very Satisfied-1-1" />
<input type="radio" name="questionOpt[1]" value="Satisfied-1-2" />
<input type="radio" name="questionOpt[1]"  value="Neutral-1-3" />
<input type="radio" name="questionOpt[1]" value="Dissatisfied-1-4" />
<input type="radio" name="questionOpt[1]" value="Very Dissatisfied-1-5" />

<input type="radio" name="questionOpt[2]" value="Very Satisfied-2-1" />
<input type="radio" name="questionOpt[2]" value="Satisfied-2-2" />
<input type="radio" name="questionOpt[2]"  value="Neutral-2-3" />
<input type="radio" name="questionOpt[2]" value="Dissatisfied-2-4" />
<input type="radio" name="questionOpt[2]" value="Very Dissatisfied-2-5" />

<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" />
```

When user select the radio button , I want to write the value of radio button to array and then pass it to the controller of my asp.net mvc project.

This is what I have tried :

```
<input type="hidden" id="resultSelect" name="resultSelect" value="1,2,3,4,5"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
var clicks = new Array();
$(document).ready(function () {
    for (var i = 1; i <= count_; i++) {
        $("input:radio[name='questionOpt["+i+"]']").click(function () {
            clicks.push($(this).val());
        });
    }
});
$("#submit").click(function () {
    for (var y = 0; y<clicks.length; y++) {
        $("#resultSelect").val(clicks[y]);       
    }
 });

</script>
```

I write in my controller like this :

```
  string result= frm["resultSelect"].ToString();
```

When I click on radio button `Very Satisfied-1-1` and `Dissatisfied-2-4`, Then when I debug it, there's only `Dissatisfied-2-4` in `result` string.

Could anyone tell me how could I get two of radio button value `Very Satisfied-1-1` and `Dissatisfied-2-4` as an array `["Very Satisfied-1-1","Dissatisfied-2-4"]` in `result` string of my controller.

Thanks.

Comment: IDs must be _unique_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$("#submit").click(function ()
{
    var selectedIdsStr = clicks.join(",");
    $("#resultSelect").val(selectedIdsStr);       
});
```

and please also wrap above code inside `document.ready`

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting values in the for loop, you can use [`serailizeArray`](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) method:

> Encode a set of form elements as an array of names and values.

```
$("#submit").click(function () {
    var arr = $('input[type=radio]').serializeArray(); 
    $("#resultSelect").val(arr);       
});
```